# Can two different ViewModels point to the same object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Say I have two ViewModels which both complete the properties of the object. I get some attributes in one view and the others in another view. How can i bind them together in an object? 
Here's the class Booking

```
public class Booking
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string departFrom { set; get; }
        public string departTo { set; get; }
        public int memberID { get; set; }

        public DateTime departureDate { set; get; }
        public DateTime returnDate { set; get; }

       [ForeignKey("departTo")]
       public virtual Flight flight { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey("memberID")]
       public virtual Memeber member { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I here the ViewModel for the first view where I get only the dates and departFrom and departTo locations:

```
public class BookingViewModel1
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string departFrom { set; get; }
        public string departTo { set; get; }

        public DateTime departureDate { set; get; }
        public DateTime returnDate { set; get; }
        [ForeignKey("departTo")]
        public virtual Flight flight { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to send these values to another View so I can enter the member attributes in order to save the Booking in my database.
Here's the other ViewModel:

```
public class BookingViewModel2
    {
        public int memberID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("memeberID")]
        public virtual Member member { get; set; }
    }
```

So in the controller I want to bind them together so they can point to the same object.

Comment: Please read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your question is very unclear but I'll try.  ViewModels aren't supposed to talk to each other in the way I think you want.  They should only be passing data to and from their respective models.  In the model you put the data where it belongs (a database, a file, a setting, a shared static property, etc.) and then you can access it from other parts of your code accordingly.

Comment: @Div I edited the post

Comment: The terminology is _view_ not _viewmodel_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do this there are different ways to do that one of them is by using

*Tuple* likes this on the start of the view

**Note never written model inside the double quote like i did**

```
@model Tuple <"OneModel","twoModel">
@html.TextBoxFor(model.item1.modelPropertie)
@html.TextBoxFor(model.item2.modelPropertie)
```